# A GET form and a POST form on the same page

Tags: html, forms, post, get

I'm having a noobie problem getting my head round how I can make this work.

I have a page listing products from my DB. Above the list of products is a GET form with two dropdowns in it to choose how many products per-page, and the sort order.

Then to the left of my listing I have a sidebox containing a POST form with all the sub-categories in a particular category presented with checkboxes so users can refine their search.

Because the sidebox contains lots of options it seems best to have this form as a POST otherwise I'll end up with potentially urls with 10s of category_ids in it, however that means when I update either of the dropdowns in the GET form I need the info from POST to be sent along.

I've tried just having one big POST form covering both bits but because they're in different s this doesn't validate.

Whats the best way of doing this, I can't figure it out!

EDIT: Here's a fiddle of my attempt to put all elements into one POST form, it doesn't validate because of the different divs and I can't wrap them in one DIV because it'd bugger up my layout, ie there's meant to be the list of products to the right of sidebox and under filterbar - http://jsfiddle.net/FwQNn/

```
<div id="prodlistFilterBarWrapper">
        <form name="filter" action="index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=45" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="main_page" value="index" />
            <div id="filterbarwrapper"><span class="filterBarTextperpage">&nbsp;per-page&nbsp;</span>
                <div id="perpagecontainer">
                    <select name="perpage" id="perpage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="40">40</option>
                        <option value="60">60</option>
                        <option value="80">80</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="sortordercontainer">
                    <select name="sortorder" id="sortorder" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                        <option value="bestselling">Best Selling</option>
                        <option value="pricelowhigh" selected="selected">Price low-high</option>
                        <option value="pricehighlow">Price high-low</option>
                        <option value="nameaz">Name a-z</option>
                        <option value="nameza">Name z-a</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div id="sidebox">
        <div id="sideboxheaderbgtop"><span class="yellowText" style="margin-left:15px">Refine</span> <span class="whiteText">search</span></div>
        <div id="sideboxPriceRange"></div>
        <div id="sideboxCatsWithCheckBoxes">
        <div class="sideboxHeading">Irish Gifts &amp; Souvenirs</div>
        <div class="sideboxDotSpacer"></div>
        <div class='sideboxSubCat'><input type="checkbox" name="subcats[]" value="20" checked="checked" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Decorations</div>
        <div class='sideboxSubCat'><input type="checkbox" name="subcats[]" value="48" checked="checked" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Keyrings</div>
        <div class='sideboxSubCat'><input type="checkbox" name="subcats[]" value="25" checked="checked" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Whiskey </div>
        <div class='sideboxSubCat'><input type="checkbox" name="subcats[]" value="15" checked="checked" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Novelties</div>
        <div class='sideboxSubCat'><input type="checkbox" name="subcats[]" value="44" checked="checked" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Titanic</div>
        <div class='sideboxSubCat'><input type="checkbox" name="subcats[]" value="18" checked="checked" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Glassware</div>
        <div class='sideboxSubCat'><input type="checkbox" name="subcats[]" value="43" checked="checked" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;football</div>
        <div class='sideboxSubCat'><input type="checkbox" name="subcats[]" value="8" checked="checked" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dolls</div>
        <input type="image" src="update.png" alt="Update" title=" Update " id="sideboxUpdateButton" />
        </form>
        <div class="sideboxBottomSpace"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you need the information from both forms, then they should be just one form.

Comment: can you some code? it will help understanding your question.

Comment: Why does it not validate when you use one form?  Are they in different frames?

Comment: Here's some code - I had tried just having it in one form as all as a POST but it doesn't validate - here's what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/FwQNn/

Comment: If you look in your fiddle, you will see a red `div` and a red `form `tag.  This means your html structure is somehow wrong, you probably have too many/too few divs, which is why it doesn't validate.  But in principle you should be fine with one form.

Comment: I think I've got this sorted. It was indeed the layout managed to get messed up somehow, a missing DIV here and there was causing the problem. Thanks for the help anyway, sorry for wasting time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is 
1. Change the Dropdown gets to posts if you have to pass along the left side data
2. Include hidden fields in the Dropdown form which are populated when you choose the different categories from the left side..This is easily done with a simple bit of javascript